# What's the appropriate use of removeListener in this case?

Tags: node.js

Bot library for Discord,

```
bot.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    // do some stuff
    bot.removeListener('messageCreate', msg);
});
```

An error I get often is `listener must be a function`.
messageCreate is fired when a message is received, msg is a reference to the message class, which contains the message id, author, etc.

What I'm trying to get is the bot waiting for a specific reply back from the user, such as Yes or No.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `bot` is a Node's `EventEmitter`, you can use `once` method instead of `on` so that it automatically removes the listener after the listener is called once.

```
bot.once('messageCreate', msg => {
  // do some stuff
  // you don't need to remove the listener by yourself!
});
```

To straightly answer your question, the second argument of `removeListener` must be the listener function that you passed to `on`.

```
var listener = msg => {
  // do some stuff
  bot.removeListener('messageCreate', listener);
};
bot.on('messageCreate', listener);
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a lot simpler than I was expecting. Worked as expected!

Comment: What will be replacement for function bot.once in new version of API?

Comment: I'm not sure about Discord API. Do you have a link to its API document?

Answer (score 0):

In discord V12 you can remove the listener like this inside the `ready` event if you are using some other type of command handler like `commando`

```js
bot.once("ready", () => {
   bot.removeListener("message", client._events.message[0]);
}
```